# Nginx not able to file gunicorn socket file http 502

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

5 connect() to unix:/var/run/mygunicorn.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream

my gunicorn.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=abc
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/abc/mywork/xyz
ExecStart=/home/abc/shoenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/run/mygunicorn.sock xyz.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

gunicorn.socket file

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/var/run/mygunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

nginx server new sites-available

```
server {
listen 80;listen [::]:80;
server_name <gunicorn server ip>;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/abc/shopcart;
}
location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/mygunicorn.sock;
}

}
```

I can curl it from gunicorn server `curl --unix-socket /var/run/mygunicorn.sock localhost`

But when I try from nginx server it cannot find socket file
`unix:/var/run/mygunicorn.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream`

socket file exists though `srw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Apr  3 06:18 /var/run/mygunicorn.sock`